# how to read tensorflow confusion matrix rows and columns

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

For my 2 classes (`1 = [0, 1]` and `0 = [1, 0]`) CNN model I use `tf.confusion_matrix` to finding a confusion matrix for the model. one of my results is like below for validation set:

```
[ [1800  17] 
  [283  600] ]
```

after doing some search I see more than one type of reading, some of them say `[[TN  FP][FN  TP]]`, but some others read it in this way `[[TP  FP][FN  TN]]`, I am confused which one is right for my case? please give me an answer that depends on scientific research if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The truth is behind the code ;)
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/confusion_matrix.py

> Class labels are expected to   start at 0. For example, if
>   `num_classes` is 3, then the possible labels   would be `[0, 1, 2]`.
>    Note that the possible labels are assumed to be `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`,
>     resulting in a 5x5 confusion matrix.

So better don't pass one hot tensors to the function ;) (tf.argmax might be a good friend here)

This means that the first element (row 0 col 0) corresponds with the number of elements that have been properly classified for class 0.

Row 0 col 1 will correspond with the missclassified elements of the class 0 and so on.

Comment: sorry, the only thing that I want to be sure about is the sort of confusion matrix for example the rows and columns are ordered as (row1=0,row2=1) (col1=0,col2=1) or in reverse of that (row1=1,row2=0) (col1=1,col2=0)

Comment: This is the right sorting (row1=0,row2=1) (col1=0,col2=1), this is what I tried to explain you above. Read carefully this part is important "Note that the possible labels are assumed to be [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], resulting in a 5x5 confusion matrix."

Comment: thank you dear, your answer is exactly what I understand it, you mean this order [[TN  FP][FN  TP]]? sorry for asking is there any prove for that? or a resource that prove it?

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/confusion_matrix.py